Does a user specified in a Dockerfile used to create a Docker Container Image have to exist on the host when the Image is run as a Container?
It is possible, and optional, to specify a user in a Dockerfile. Docker Images are created by building a Dockerfile.
If a username is specified, a process which runs inside a Docker Container created from the Docker Image will run as the specified user.
Does that username have to exist as a user on the host Operating System when the Docker Container is run?
What happens if the Container is run and the user does not exist on the host system?
In a Dockerfile, a username can be specified using
user: <username>


Have you tested this? What were the results?

Well, it runs fine. I don't know what to make of that. If the container has a mounted volume and it creates files, then if those files have a different UID than the current user on the host, the host user cannot read, write, delete etc those files. That is another question however

host and container have different user namespaces.  container users are distinct from host users one can exist distinctly from the other

@erik258 I may be misunderstanding your point - but what you have said appears to be the opposite of how it works. Consider this: I run a Docker Container. That Container runs a process with user "exampleuser" which has UID 1234. The Container creates some files in a volume mounted from the host path /data-docker/exampleuser. Those files are created with UID 1234. The Container shuts down. There is a user on the host which has UID 1234. Suddenly, some random user on the host has the same permissions as the Docker Container's User.

"Suddenly, some random user on the host has the same permissions as the Docker Container's User."  Let's distinguish between a UID - literally any  uint32 - and a "user on the system."  If I create a user 10123 and create a filesystem on a USB disk, then you plug it into your system, it's still owned by the same UID even though you don't have a user associated with  that ID.  This isn't a docker thing, it's jut how UIDs work.

@erik258 Right, so that's exactly my point. If you create a user with the id 10123, then that user will have permissions for these files.

Users don't need to "exist", either on the host or in the container.
For a basic example, assuming your host shell is a "rich" shell like bash or zsh, you can try running
docker run -u "$RANDOM" busybox id

This will pick a random numeric user ID and run the main container process as that ID.  The main process here is id(1), which just prints out the current effective user and group IDs and their names if known.  There's a small chance, if you run it enough times, that it will pick a user ID that happens to exist in the container's /etc/passwd, but most of the time it will be an arbitrary random user.
It's often a best practice for a container to run not as root, but beyond the user ID not being 0 it doesn't usually matter what the uid actually is.  So one thing I've seen somewhat regularly is to set up the container, with its various files world-readable, and then switch to some non-root USER at the end of the Dockerfile.  Often the image will run adduser(8) to create the user, but it's not really necessary.
FROM some-standard-language-image

# Run the entire build sequence as root
USER root
RUN apt-get install ...
WORKDIR /app
COPY language-specific-dependencies.yml ./
RUN install-language-specific-dependencies
COPY ./ ./
RUN language-specific-build

# Only now switch to non-root
USER 12345  # the specific uid doesn't matter
CMD ["my-application"]

You can run this container even if user 12345 isn't listed in either the host's or container's /etc/passwd file.  Nothing untoward happens.
The situation is slightly more complicated if the container depends on storage that can be bind-mounted from the host system.  In that case, the container process's user or group ID needs to match something that can write to the host directory.  The image can't know what that host-specific uid or gid will be, so you need to specify it when you run the container.  Again, there's no particular requirement that the user "exists" anywhere; it's possible for the host file to be owned by an arbitrary numeric uid (sudo chown 9876 ./data/).

See this is the source of my confusion. User namespaces are not independent between the host and the Docker container. It matters more if you have a mounted volume, because your container might see files which were created on the host, and it may also create files, which the host can then see. If you happen to pick the same UID, then a random host user can read and write data which was created by a Docker container user, and vice-versa.

If you can design your container setup so that all of the code lives in the image and nothing is stored in the container filesystem, then you won't need to bind-mount anything.  This also helps environments like Kubernetes, where you can't usefully bind-mount and where you're frequently running multiple replicas of the same container.  The container also can't write to any host directories other than what's explicitly mounted when the container is run, so the security implications here should be limited.

In many circumstances this isn't practical. There can be many different reasons for wanting to persist data. It might make debugging easier. For example, if logs are saved to a volume accessible from the host, then they can be easily read even if the container is not running (which is likely to happen if it goes wrong and the process crashes for some reason, such as a software bug). Or, it might be for backup reasons. For example, if you are running some (general) database technology inside a container, you may periodically take snapshots of the data in the volume.

docker logs doesn't depend on the container filesystem or the container running at all; if you have a production-oriented log collector, you can review logs without access to the container system itself.  You can generally run database management tools like pgdump or pgrestore from other systems, so you could run a dump on the host system against a containerized database without the database having bind-mounted storage.  Data does actually have to live somewhere, admittedly, but limiting the number of places it's actually stored can be helpful.

The point being you may not be using postgres. (Kafka, for example? Or something more exotic? Or even just storing some files on disk...) docker logs might not be the easiest way to read your logs. You might have logs which write to disk only, or stdout might be redirected. I agree if there's a convenient solution involving these tools there may be no need to mount a volume.
